# How to overwrite NextJS's route handler request object construction

Tags: next.js, app-router

Our Openlitespeed web server sends incorrect parameter that's used to construct request object in NextJS resulting in an error

```
import { type NextRequest } from 'next/server';

export function GET(
    request : NextRequest,
    { params }: { params: { slug: string } }
) {
console.log('hola!')
...
The code never reached hola but instead generates this error
```

⨯ TypeError: Invalid URL
at new URL (node:internal/url:775:36)
...
code: 'ERR_INVALID_URL',
input: '/sitemap/asdasd',
base: 'https, https://localhost:3000/sitemap/asdasd'

```
notice that the base is incorrect 'https, https://localhost:3000/sitemap/asdasd' should've been 'https://localhost:3000/sitemap/asdasd'

this is proved by
running `new URL('/sitemap/asdasd', 'https, https://localhost:3000/sitemap/asdasd')` will cause the same error
while `new URL('/sitemap/asdasd', 'https://localhost:3000/sitemap/asdasd')`
will not

so my solution is to put nginx between openlitespeed (openlitespeed cannot be removed)

but what's the header I need to fix?
```

Answer (score 0):

It might not have been OLS after all, this comment resolves the problem https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/58295#issuecomment-1826453578